# How to fix 'Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js)'

Tags: node.js

I'm settung up an React+Redux-saga+ANTD application,while running the application i found this error "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot set property 'then' of undefined"

I have tried with npm modules reinstall.after npm clean cache.
I want to include i have been using windows 7 os with 32-bit.

Comment: It would help to identify your issue by providing a minimum set of code which reproduces the error.